# Prevent TFS to add all files to source control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with TFS on visual studio 2017. I had to reinstall it and now it automatically add all files in folder to source control.

By example, if I compare a file.cs with repository with winmerge, winmerge create a file.cs.bak in my folder. TFS will see the file in folder and add it to source control when I check in.

How can I disable this feature ? Before the reinstall, only files created with visual studio was added to source control.

Comment: `.tfignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,as Shayki said in his comment, you should use [`.tfignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops#tfignore-file-rules) which will help to ignore whatever files you don't want to checkin to the source control.

> You can configure which kinds of files are ignored by placing text
>   file called `.tfignore` in the folder where you want rules to apply. The
>   effects of the `.tfignore` file are recursive. However, you can create
>   `.tfignore` files in sub-folders to override the effects of a `.tfignore`
>   file in a parent folder.

```
######################################
# Ignore .cs.bak files 
*.cs.bak
```